# How can I run the example project of Google App Engine + GWT in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

Ive installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse and created a demo project using App Engine and GWT. Now I want to launch and see it. But after compile nothing else happens. Shouldn't there be an integrated browser that shows the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to right click on the project name and hit run > web application. Compiling it is for deployment, and most likely not what your looking for from running. The key differences here are hosted mode handles the cross-compilation for you, while compiling is meant for deployment of the javascript to your web server.

Comment: Woot! My first best answer, and with an awesome technology! Thanks!

Comment: This is only sort of true.  You'll end up compiling and then running locally some % of the time.  It's something like 99%/1%, though, so this is still useful advice for someone starting out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you just point your browser (any browser) to http://localhost:8080. Is that not working for you?

Comment: No. I don't have tomcat or anything else. I know there is a build-in solution in eclipse, have seen it once in a while. Any idea?

Comment: The Google Plug-in comes with an embedded Jetty server. I may have gotten the port number wrong, perhaps it's 8888. I can't really verify until I get to work.

Comment: I figured out there is a run config where you can check "use free port automatically", which was in my case 49203

Answer (score 0):

I get it running externally on the command line with 
dev_appserver . 
or to upload to the google site
appcfg update .

for python they're .py files and for java their .cmd calls
wish I could mix and match my languages/GAE environments

Answer (score 0):

You can right click your project and goto Run as > Web Application.

You can see that a local Jetty Server.

You can manually type the address http://localhost:8888 or you can access through cmd